# Writing JSON array to object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, replacewith

I have some JSON which looks like this.

```
[
{
    "items": [
        {
            "id": "xxxx",
            "description": {
                "style": "",
                "specs": ""
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "xxxx",
            "description": {
                "style": "",
                "specs": ""
            }
        }
    ],
    "category": "xxxxxx",
    "name": "xxxxxx"
},
{
    "items": [
        {
            "id": "xxxx",
            "description": {
                "style": "",
                "specs": ""
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "xxxx",
            "description": {
                "style": "",
                "specs": ""
            }
        }
    ],
    "category": "xxxxxx",
    "name": "xxxxxx"
}
]
```

It's being passed to me as 'newItem'. And is being set twice in the existing code I'm working on:

```
that.cart.addItem(newItem.toObject());
```

And later:

```
that.origCart.replaceWith(that.cart);
```

This traditionally has worked fine when 'items' was a flat list. However, the JSON above is the new JSON format and therefor I need to pass 'items' for each category/name.

Inside the 'for' loop I have this outputting what I need for each.(I need to keep them separated.)

```
newItem.items
```

However, when I attempt to perform the following I get a Type Error. (Yes, I'm going to have multiple 'carts' once I get this working.)

```
that.cart.addItem(newItem.items.toObject());

TypeError: newItem.items.toObject is not a function
```

What can I do to get 'newItem.items' to the proper type, or what operation can I substitute for to get these set properly? I tried a bunch of things I found online without success and now I'm turning to the experts. Just not my forte (yet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to call an items function from the newItems object even though items is an Array. Try the following:

```
that.cart.addItem(newItem.items);
```

Comment: Sorry I posted this multi-tasking and I messed up. I fixed the two lines above. that.cart.addItem(newItem.toObject()); that.cart.addItem(newItem.items.toObject());

Comment: This ultimately worked. I changed to example: that.cart.addItem(newItem.items[0]); and I get the proper data for each item. Could swear I tried this (thus why toObject was originally missing). Thanks for pushing me in the right direction.